# Fixed sidebar but responsive layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

This is a preview of the website I'm currently working on: http://jsfiddle.net/X4Yc8/

It has a fixed (full height) sidebar with a scrolling main content section.

When the width of the window is reduced (see screenshot below) the main content overlaps the sidebar. How do I ensure that this doesn't happen?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9RV2.jpg

Ideally I would like the main content to appear below the sidebar when the screen is a certain width e.g. when viewed on a mobile-sized screen

Thanks for your help in advance!

My code is:

CSS

```
    /* CSS Document */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #06C;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    float:left;
    background-color: #006;
    padding-top: 25px;
    position: fixed;
    clear: right;
}

section#settings {
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    margin-left:250px;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    position: absolute;
}

#sidebar #menubar li, #sidebar #menubar li:link, #sidebar #menubar li:visited {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
#sidebar #menubar li a, #sidebar #menubar li a:link, #sidebar #menubar li a:visited {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;   font-size: 80%;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#logo {
    height: 90px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

#sidebar #menubar li:hover {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    background-color: #06C;
}
#sidebar #menubar li a:hover {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;   font-size: 80%;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#sidebar    #menubar li#active{
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;   
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    background-color: #0066CC;
}

#sidebar #menubar  {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
h1 {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;   font-size: 150%;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
h2 {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;   font-size: 150%;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
h3 {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;   font-size: 125%;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
p {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;   font-size: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    line-height: 125%;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
<section id="sidebar">
<div id="logo"><img src="LOGO" width="200" height="89" alt="LOGO" /></div>
<ul id="menubar">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>

    </ul> 
        </section>

<section id="settings">
  <h1>Heading 1</h1>
  <p>Sed ultricies ut massa a vehicula. Nullam consequat lectus ut mauris venenatis, quis tincidunt urna malesuada. Donec pellentesque, lectus a eleifend tempus, dui ante porta tellus, nec lacinia tellus quam sed sem. Integer lorem nibh, pulvinar nec est ac, consectetur tincidunt dolor. Etiam fermentum aliquam sapien, nec eleifend arcuus dui, et vehicula tellus viverra ut. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis semper tellus eget est faucibus, et euismod quam viverra. Sed dapibus felis a mi mattis, eu ultrices tortor ultricies. Nulla facilisi. Duis blandit leo sed volutpat condimentum. Nullam molestie dictum est, quis volutpat augue faucibus eu. Pellentesque turpis ante, hendrerit id felis sit amet, semper elementum erat. Maecenas vitae justo ullamcorper, ultrices felis at, volutpat erat. Proin diam enim, ultricies ut erat sed, eleifend sagittis dui. Pellentesque diam magna, mattis non nulla nec, varius commodo tortor. 
 </p><p>
Curabitur mollis nunc eu adipiscing interdum. Nunc nec eleifend enim. Morbi congue metus justo, nec facilisis mauris vulputate id. Sed id laoreet arcu. Aliquam sed nunc ligula. Vivamus bibendum dictum nisi, in placerat lacus convallis vitae. Quisque placerat orci non quam fringilla, ac dictum ligula imperdiet. Proin vel nibh tellus. Sed pellentesque feugiat augue sed convallis. Nunc lobortis sem odio, eget tempor urna suscipit at. Vivamus accumsan, enim id cursus elementum, quam velit cursus sapien, in semper nulla ligula nec mi. Proin pretium nunc vel leo ultricies placerat. 
 </p><p>
Integer sed leo auctor, lobortis dui ut, sodales nunc. Aliquam mi risus, rutrum sit amet ultrices faucibus, tincidunt eget sapien. Nam vel purus eu dolor rutrum dapibus. Phasellus euismod erat ac gravida adipiscing. Sed ligula quam, ultricies id mollis vitae, consequat eget libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec quam velit, feugiat in facilisis vitae, gravida ac enim. Nunc venenatis enim eu aliquam ultrices. Curabitur et lorem non leo pretium vulputate in at ligula. Quisque dignissim pretium erat non suscipit. Phasellus aliquet dolor at sapien egestas sollicitudin. Fusce eget est sed tellus mollis eleifend laoreet a lectus. 
</p>
</section>
<div style='clear:both;'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I couldn't post this earlier, but this is an example of how I'd like the content to appear on a smaller screen/mobile: 

http://imgur.com/6oiXYNI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use css @media to change styles based on window width, eg:

```
@media (max-width: 600px){
 #sidebar{
    position:relative;
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
  }
 #menubar li{
 display:inline;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X4Yc8/2/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/X4Yc8/12/

for mobile friendliness 
Try this and then add Jquery Swipe or touch to open the menu instead of always showing it

http://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
```

this line of code targets screen sizes

Comment: thanks for the tip. Andrew's solution works best for what I'm after but I've added the '@media only screen' to my css.